# The Metal Planet and the Butterfly

Tags: science-based

I am not really sure where to pose this question, so I will pose it here as it is the closest possible thing.

Recently, I read a method of comprehending eternity, and this was by imagining a planet of metal the size of the Earth. Every 100 years a butterfly would land upon it for a second, and leave shortly after. Slowly, the friction from the butterfly would wear the planet away. Once it has worn away, it would not even have been a fraction of a percentage of eternity.

I would just like to know how long something like this may take.

Comment: Hard sci-fi: the worn-off iron settles back on the iron planet because its trapped inside the planet's gravity well. The mass of the planet stays constant. Boom, you've got your eternity back (harder sci-fi: the piles of dead flies add mass to the planet, now you've got negative eternity).

Comment: Hello Bob, and welcome. Unfortunately, I don't see how this is relevant to worldbuilding. You can [edit] your question to clarify that, but as it stands, I'm voting to put this on hold as not about worldbuilding. If you want answers based in real-world science, as you have indicated by tagging this [science-based], you would need to account for the fact that the butterfly must come from somewhere *and* that the matter worn away by it is unlikely to achieve escape velocity. Also, specifying what metric you use for "size" (mass, volume, radius, ...?) would be useful if you want good answers.

Comment: A metal planet would be considerable more dense than Earth; if it has the same size its gravitational pull will be way harder. So the butterfly could not take off. Over time, the added mass of all the dead butterfly will cause the planet to collapse into a black hole.

Comment: In addition to other issues mentioned, this is a poor way of comprehending eternity; because it is not a fraction of a percentage: It is zero percent, no matter how long a period we imagine, or how far in the future we can stretch our imagination. Zero! The conclusion (a fraction of a percent) necessarily **still** implies eternity is **finite**, that we can compute a percent of it. Imagining any finite number is not an aid to "comprehending eternity". Especially since you clearly realize such a slow process (with a supernatural butterfly) is finite and can be estimated (as Mike Scott did)!

Comment: @DanBron Quite right. The butterfly's wing would have to brush the metal planet so it scrapes off a miniscule bit moving at escape velocity or above. For some reason this seems quite improbable.

Answer (score 2):

A butterfly has a mass of around 0.1g. Figure it's not going to scrape away more than a millionth of its own mass in metal from one landing, so that's 0.1 of a microgramme every hundred years, or a gramme every billion years (1E9). The mass of the Earth is 6E24g, and since the Earth is mostly made of metal, that's close enough. It will thus take about 6E33 years, or six decillion.

Comment: I may be wrong but it's entirely possible that in six decillion years the universe has undergone heat death/big crunch/whatever, no longer exists, and "eternity" has in fact ended.

Comment: @F1Krazy No the universe will still be around. Not according to most current cosmology. This takes so much longer. Six decillion years is only a brief moment in what time remains for the cosmos.